# use php function in c#

Tags: c#, php

I am converting Traditional Chinese to Simplified Chinese using a [tool developed by mediawiki](https://code.google.com/p/mediawiki-zhconverter/). It's written in php. I have to use php to call the function in it.

The function call is like :

```
echo MediaWikiZhConverter::convert("打印机", "zh-tw");
```

I want to invoke the convert func in my C# program.

How can I do it?
Is [Phalanger](http://phalanger.codeplex.com/) a suitable way?

Comment: It would probably be easier to reimplement it in C#...

Comment: If you compile php script using phalanger, you'll get usual .NET library that you can simply reference to your C# project but I agree with @ThomasLevesque

Comment: Short answer. You can't. You can however pass the arguments as GET parameters to a web script that in turn calls the function

Answer (score 1):

just make a webrequest to your webserver running this extension. pass the two arguments in the webrequest, get them through the function, and return the result in a webresponse :)

Comment: Eek, so you first translate every word by issuing the webrequest to another server each time? Why not fixing it in the C# application.

Comment: well, if this is a fullblown tool to translate words, translating that into c# is one hell of a job i think :/

Comment: No I mean translating from withing the c# tool with a library instead of using a online webservice.

Comment: @PoweRoy indeed, if the tool/library already exists i would go for that, if you NEED to use the online tool, you could always batchconvert alot of sentences at once :)

Comment: Thank you for your ideas and suggestions! I will try to set a php webservice and make a webrequest.